# Statistic analysis of results (t-testing, CHI Squared)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, anova

I am trying to analyse whether people are more conscious about using a list of tools to better protect their vehicles in different settings.

- So my null hypothesis is that people are not any more conscious about
  the overall state of their vehicle in different environments.
- My non-null hypothesis is that people are conscious about their
  vehicle in different environments and they make use of tools to
  protect themselves.

So I have the results below:

```
Participant       Car Parked In Drive   Car Parked On Street    Car Parked In Parking Lot

1                     5                       2                     3
2                     2                       1                     2
3                     3                       3                     1
4                     4                       4                     1
5                     2                       2                     3
6                     3                       3                     3
7                     5                       5                     5
8                     3                       1                     3
9                     2                       3                     3
10                    1                       2                     3
__________________________________________________________________________________
Mean                  3                       2.6                   2.7
```

The question is how do I statistically test my data to see if my null hypothesis holds true? I looked at t-testing but that is only with two data sets. Here I have three sets

I am so sorry I am new to statistical testing here, so any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: As the samples are paired, you could consider the Friedman test. It generalizes the sign test to more than two samples.

Comment: @MichaelM thank you for this! what is the difference between this Friedman test and ANOVA test?

Comment: It's a non-parametric ANOVA for paired samples. Classic F-test is inappropriate due to the paired nature of your data.

Comment: Are the data scores (e.g. Likert scale)? counts of something? If numerical, maybe ANOVA block design OK. Freidman is nonparametric block design. 'Pair' is for two; 'block would be for 3 or more (as here).